# Search and compare two columns in excel

Tags: excel, compare

i have to columns in excel.

```
a      d
b      f
c      c
d      e
x
y
z
e
```

the secong list is a subset of first list.

i want to search the 1st list for the valus present in the 2nd and put it in 3rd column  like

```
a      d   present
b      f   absent
c      c   present
d      e   present
x
y
z
e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B4,$A$1:$A$8,0))=TRUE,"Absent","Present")
```

Comment: why do i only get present for evrything.I have just pasted the above in column c for test in with my data in a and b columns

Comment: You have to change cell address as per your requirement. Check once in match function first parameter should be relative.

Comment: yes i got it but i have to change the cell value B1,B2,B3,B4 for each cell and put the corespondiong formula in coressiponding row but is possible to make it generic like `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1-4,$A$1:$A$8,0))=TRUE,"Absent","Present")`

Comment: i have about 4000 rows to search and compare

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$8,0))=TRUE,"Absent","Present") Use this and drag this as long as you want. I am unable to understand why are you using (B1-4) in match formula.

Comment: hi prabhat one more help, is it possible to append to the thrid column say if the thrid column contains munish in one row where data is present i want it to be appended like present-munish

Comment: Yes its possible use this.                                                                  =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B5,$A$1:$A$8,0))=TRUE,"Absent","Present" & "  " &  INDEX($A$1:$B$8,MATCH(B5,$A$1:$A$8,0),1,1))